# Problem registering an ENS name on the testnet

Tags: myetherwallet, ens

**My Goal**

I'm trying to register a name on the Ropsten testnet using the FIFSRegistrar located at 0x21397c1a1f4acd9132fe36df011610564b87e24b. I am using [MEW](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts) to send the transaction.

**Label and Hashes**

I'll refer to the name as "myName.test", but use the real hashes.

The hash of my label is sha3('myName') = 0xc99b34b53e4b2e6ede6d30a0bb7d62dbb1c54f68113c9c189f572687fc778ecc.

The namehash I am registering is namehash('myName.test') = 0x4c432675fc6a71ce63b71b12db314c4857a215abc7768ad213ebbcf88bdb5bd3.

**Transaction Attempt**

[My transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x51a13d3b8f688916b1f299b9ff162836a0b2dad50f4ada9e94a66ec48bdde166) is mined and seems to work as expected. In particular I can see in the Event Logs that it called the `setSubnodeOwner()` function of the ENSRegistry located at 0x112234455c3a32fd11230c42e7bccd4a84e02010. So far so good.

However, when I call the `owner()` function of the ENSRegistry and pass it the namehash of my name, it returns 0x0. Looks like my name is not registered after all...

Any idea why it is not working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong namehash. When you use the correct namehash, the contract shows you as the owner.

### Namehash

The correrct namehash of your label hash under `.test` is `0x944f155a1f09749e7a9ee390f3b20926c9a285939187135286e5a1b7fd39b8c2`. Your address, `0x3a81ff1fdf10faa57e3d6f0628613ce276ee4f39`, owns that namehash on Ropsten. You can confirm that on [MyEtherWallet.com](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts) with these steps:

1. Choose the Ropsten network at top-right
2. Select the ENS Registry contract from the dropdown
3. Click <kbd>Access</kbd>
4. Choose the `owner` function from the dropdown
5. Copy in the namehash to the `node` field
6. Click <kbd>READ</kbd>

[image: Confirming ENS ownership]

### Calculating Namehash

Here is a step-by-step calculation of the namehash:

```
from web3utils import web3

# namehash(ROOT)
rootnode = b'\0' * 32

# labelhash('test')
testhash = web3.sha3('test'.encode('utf-8'))

# namehash('test')
testnode = web3.sha3(rootnode + testhash)

# labelhash('??myname??')
mynamehash = web3.toAscii('0xc99b34b53e4b2e6ede6d30a0bb7d62dbb1c54f68113c9c189f572687fc778ecc')

# namehash('??myname??.test')
mynamenode = web3.sha3(testnode + mynamehash)

assert web3.toHex(mynamenode) == '0x944f155a1f09749e7a9ee390f3b20926c9a285939187135286e5a1b7fd39b8c2'
```

Note that this uses a python library, [web3utils](https://github.com/carver/web3utils.py), which requires a local node.