# ENS subNode register

Tags: ens

I've tried several times to add a subNode to my ENS domain through MEW/Contracts.
Keep getting: `Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination]`

When clicked on "Write" to make the it also starts with Gas Limit = -1.
When changed to different amounts on the several times I tried, it keep failing to create the subNode.

Also, it cost significant amount of Tx cost on gas by now, which has not been returned after the failed transaction.

Comment: Could you provide the failing transaction ID (or link to it on a blockchain explorer)?

Comment: Thank you for having a look.... This is one of the failed the TxID: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8872d4e6c37e5a5b8b723c85d9499b0fb8ab5a0c42ea66bb87f2805d10eea5c6

Answer (score 1):

### Why is this failing?

The transaction sender doesn't own the parent node. That will always be the reason that a `setSubnodeOwner(...)` call will fail with a "bad jump".

From [ENS.sol](https://github.com/ethereum/ens/blob/master/contracts/ENS.sol#L62):

```
/**
 * Transfers ownership of a subnode sha3(node, label) to a new address. May only be
 * called by the owner of the parent node.
 * @param node The parent node.
 * @param label The hash of the label specifying the subnode.
 * @param owner The address of the new owner.
 */
function setSubnodeOwner(bytes32 node, bytes32 label, address owner) only_owner(node) {
    var subnode = sha3(node, label);
    NewOwner(node, label, owner);
    records[subnode].owner = owner;
}

// Permits modifications only by the owner of the specified node.
modifier only_owner(bytes32 node) {
    if (records[node].owner != msg.sender) throw;
    _;
}
```

The parent node that you need to own is the one you supplied as your first argument, which is:

```
0x4c6828bff2e6f9cb971ca9a106f0a5a653c8128287fcd8f4e5cf2ab9bd45da73
```

(according to etherscan)

### Why might I not be the owner?

Some of the most likely reasons are:

**No one is the owner**

Maybe you have not run `finalizeAuction()` on your .eth name?

**The sender is incorrect**

An example scenario is:

- You are juggling several accounts.
- You purchased the name with a non-default account.
- You forgot to set `from` in the `setSubnodeOwner(...)` transaction to the owning account.

**The node is incorrect**

Maybe you own the name, but you calculated the node (aka "namehash") incorrectly. See "Calculating Namehash" in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/24930/1461), but with 'eth' instead of 'test'.

For reference, the namehash of 'eth' is:

```
> web3.toHex(ens.namehash('eth'))
'0x93cdeb708b7545dc668eb9280176169d1c33cfd8ed6f04690a0bcc88a93fc4ae'
```

(source: [ens.py](https://github.com/carver/ens.py))

### For this specific case

There's still not enough information to be sure. We can eliminate "The sender is incorrect" because no one owns the node that was the first argument to your call. Check out the other two reasons, and feel free to comment for follow-up.

Comment: Somehow I got through the proccess and the SubNode is set. Thank you for the advises.